# variable range, don't overwrite

Tags: javascript, variables, range, overwrite

I have a part of the js code:

```
var res; 

r.open("POST", target, true); 
r.setRequestHeader("Content-type","application/x-www-form-urlencoded"); 

r.onreadystatechange = function(){ 
    if(r.readyState==4 && r.status==200){ 
        if(data) { 
            res = r.responseText;
        } 
        r = null; 
    } 
} 

alert(res);
```

The problem is that **res = r.responseText** doesn't change the value of **res** variable and the alert is showing *undefined*

Does anyone know how to fix that?

Answer (score 0):

Your alert is running before `res` is set. Try your `alert` in your `if` block where you set `res`.

Comment: It's working, but the script above is a part of bigger function and i want to return res variable from this function. When i do **return r.responseText;** istead **res = r.responseText;** id doesn't working.